# Magento2 - Running di:compile stops at 57% in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, permissions, compilation, regenerate

> Class Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessageInterfaceFactory does not
> exist   Class Vendor\Extension\Model\Mail\TransportBuilder\Interceptor
> generation error: The requested class did not generate properly,
> because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If ---
> after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the
> 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested
> class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class
> object to the signature of the related construct method, only.

I found some solutions but none worked.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Run the command: (To give permissions to generated folder) as:

> chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/generated

and run

> bin/magento setup:di:compile

Answer (score 0):

Try following commands in your magento root folder

```
chmod -R 777 var generated pub
chown systemusername:systemusername var generated pub
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete folder

rm -rf generated/*

and try again
(and check that you are running the command from a user account and not from root)